# JQuery Animate Translate3D -100% to 0%

Tags: jquery, css

Just faking a quick animation of a YouTube style page loader.

So with JQuery, I'm trying to animate:
transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
to
transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0);

So from -100% to 0% (left to right).

I'm using this at the moment:

```
$('#progress-bar').animate({
    'opacity': '0'
}, {
    step: function (now, fx) {
        $(this).css('-webkit-transform',"translate3d(" + now + "%, 0, 0)");
    },
    duration: 5000,
    easing: 'linear',
    queue: false,
    complete: function () {
       // alert('Animation is done');
        $(this).fadeOut();
    }
}, 'linear');
```

A few of problems I'm having. If I use text-indent it goes to pixels. And if I use opacity it obviously fades to 0, but they all seem to animation from 1% to 0%, not -100% to 0%.

Any ideas on how to fix this demo?

Here's the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/rhysyg03/xqrLmwmp/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the range of `opacity` is 0-1, so `now` is in-between. try doing `now * 100`:

```
$('#progress-bar').animate({
    'opacity': '0'
}, {
    step: function (now, fx) {
        $(this).css('-webkit-transform',"translate3d(" + now*100 + "%, 0, 0)");
    },
    duration: 5000,
    easing: 'linear',
    queue: false,
    complete: function () {
       // alert('Animation is done');
        $(this).fadeOut();
    }
}, 'linear');
```

Comment: Hey thanks mate. Definitely helps. If I do now*-100 it gives me what I need. However, it also makes it disapear because opacity is at zero. Is there another property that wouldn't change anything visual for that div?

Comment: Ended up getting it going with a text indent and "translate3d(" + now*-1 + "%, 0, 0)");